# python3で辞書のkeyの値を出力したい

Tags: python, python3

python3で多重レベルの辞書の値を出力したい場合、get()で存在確認する(No.1)、inで存在確認(No.2)するとネストが深くなってしまうのですが、より簡潔に書くにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？また、No.1、No.2の使い分けはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

```
cats = [
    "Henri",
    "Grumpy",
    "Lucy",
]
animals = {
    "cats": cats,
    "octopi": {},
    "emus": {},
}
life = {
    "animals": animals,
    "plants": {},
    "other": {},
}

# No.1
if life.get("animals") != None:
    if life.get("animals").get("cats") != None:
        print(life.get("animals").get("cats"))

# No.2
if "animals" in life:
    if "cats" in life["animals"]:
        print(life["animals"]["cats"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getはデフォルトの返答を第二引数を渡せるため、以下の書き方ができます。

```
# no.1 
animals = life.get("animals", {})  # もしanimalsが無い場合は空辞書が返される
cats = animals.get("cats")  # もし上で空辞書が返った場合、catsも無いのでNoneが返される
if cats is not None:
    print(cats)

# つなげると
cats = life.get("animals", {}).get("cats")
if cats is not None:
    print(cats)
```